# RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX upgrade - 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' ... errors

Tags: .net-3.5, telerik, asp.net-3.5, upgrade, rad-controls

**Distinct error:**

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SourceDragNode' and no extension method 'SourceDragNode' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
  protected void rtvContainers_NodeDrop(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     // Update the parent container for the source node
     this.EditObject = OrganizationContainer.Get(new Guid(e.SourceDragNode.Value));
     ViewState["EditId"] = this.EditObject.OrganizationContainerId;
     this.EditObject.ParentOrganizationContainerId = new Guid(e.DestDragNode.Value);
     this.BindForm();
     this.EditObject.EndEdit();
     this.EditObject.Save();

     // Rebind the tree
     if (rtvContainers.SelectedNode != null)
        rtvContainers.SelectedNode.Selected = false;
     e.SourceDragNode.Selected = true;
     BindContainersTreeview();
     BindParentContainerCombobox();
  }
```

**Distinct error:**

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'DestDragNode' and no extension method 'DestDragNode' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
  protected void rtvContainers_NodeDrop(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     // Update the parent container for the source node
     this.EditObject = OrganizationContainer.Get(new Guid(e.SourceDragNode.Value));
     ViewState["EditId"] = this.EditObject.OrganizationContainerId;
     this.EditObject.ParentOrganizationContainerId = new Guid(e.DestDragNode.Value);
     this.BindForm();
     this.EditObject.EndEdit();
     this.EditObject.Save();

     // Rebind the tree
     if (rtvContainers.SelectedNode != null)
        rtvContainers.SelectedNode.Selected = false;
     e.SourceDragNode.Selected = true;
     BindContainersTreeview();
     BindParentContainerCombobox();
  }
```

**Distinct error:**

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NodeClicked' and no extension method 'NodeClicked' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
  protected void sectionTree_NodeExpand(object o, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     Guid? parentId = NullableParser.GetNullable<Guid>(e.NodeClicked.Value);
     if (parentId.HasValue)
     {
        foreach (SiteSection section in SiteSectionCollection.GetChildrenOf(parentId.Value))
        {
           RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode(section.Name, section.AssetId.ToString());
           node.ExpandMode = ExpandMode.ServerSideCallBack;
           e.NodeClicked.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
     }
  }
```

**Distinct error:**

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NodeEdited' and no extension method 'NodeEdited' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
  protected void rtvContainers_NodeEdit(object o, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     // Update the parent container for the source node
     this.EditObject = OrganizationContainer.Get(new Guid(e.NodeEdited.Value));
     ViewState["EditId"] = this.EditObject.OrganizationContainerId;
     this.EditObject.Name = e.NodeEdited.Text;
     this.BindForm();
     this.EditObject.EndEdit();
     this.EditObject.Save();
  }
```

**Distinct error:**

'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NewText' and no extension method 'NewText' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code:**

```
  protected void RadTreeView1_NodeEdit(object o, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     // Load the folder being edited
     RadTreeNode nodeEdited = e.NodeEdited;
     Guid currentFolderId = new Guid(nodeEdited.Value);

     try
     {
        // Try to change the folder's name
        UpdateFolder(currentFolderId, e.NewText);
        nodeEdited.Text = e.NewText;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        errorValidator.IsValid = false;
        errorValidator.ErrorMessage = "Unable to update folder name: " + e.NodeEdited.Text;
        LogHelper.Log(ex);
     }
  }
```

**Background:**

When upgrading from "RadControls for ASP.NET" to "RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX", I ran into several issues.  The web.config file was converted by the Upgrade Wizard.  I started with 233 .NET compilation errors (28 distinct errors) which I quickly resolved, but I still have 36 errors (13 distinct issues) left from drastic API changes that I still haven't resolved.  I will post these 13 errors as questions on stack overflow to save me some time.  While I'm waiting I will try downloading their control demos and understand how the controls work for their newest release and answer them myself for those others haven't answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out all of these errors were from old demo projects... I clicked "Find All References" on all of these methods, and none came up.  So I'm commenting them out and forgetting about them since they're not in the API of the newest release.